# Member Leave Message - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've looked and all the posts I could find reference an older version of discord.py when it comes to sending member leave messages. The code below doesn't give an error, yet also doesn't send a message when a member leaves a server. Am I missing something? I've looked at the documentation and this makes sense...

```
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(762921541787975686)
    await channel.send(f"{member} quit on the 1 yard line (left the server).")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a stroke and forgot to add @client.event above it -_-
Working code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(762921541787975686)
    await channel.send(f"{member} quit on the 1 yard line (left the server).")
```